# Access to Android/data/"SOME APP FOLDER" on Android 11 api30

Tags: android

how can i access to /Android/data/"Target app" in Android R (11)?

```
private boolean isPermissionGranted(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        // for Android 11
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();

    }else {
        int readExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return readExternalStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }
}
public void takePermission(View view){
    if (isPermissionGranted()){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Permission is Already Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        takePermission();
    }
}

private void takePermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s" , getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent , 100);
        }catch (Exception exception){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent , 100);
        }
    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Permission Granted in Android 11 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                takePermission();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0){

        if (requestCode == 101){
            boolean readExternalStorage = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (readExternalStorage){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Read Permission is Granted in Android 10 or below", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                takePermission();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

that is working to write every where.
but when i want to write in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/"Some App Folder" i got this error:
2021-08-27 17:46:09.803 23862-23862/com.itscaptive.frpsrcchanger E/Permission_LOG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tencent.ig/SrcVersion.ini: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

anyone can help me? :)

Comment: Not possible with classic file means. Only with SAF.

Answer (score 2):

Android 11 you no longer can access data folder of other apps

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#other-apps-data

Comment: but some file manager can access data folder like ES file explorer or MT manager

Comment: @fireborrower Since those apps are actual file browsers they probably make use of the MANAGE_ALL_FILES permission that is made for this type of app BUT dont go thinking you can just use this because google will review your app and if your app's core functionality does not need this permission like a file browser would they will reject it. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files